# Capitalization of first instance of matching character in a crosswords puzzle

Tags: list, python-3.x, arraylist, puzzle

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word):
    for rows in crosswords:
        string=''.join(rows)

        if word in string:
            #finding index
            row_index=crosswords.index(rows)
            column_index=rows.index(word[0])
            return [row_index,column_index ]
    return None

def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    z=[list(i) for i in zip(*crosswords)]   
    for rows in z:          
        row_index = z.index(rows)
        single_row = ''.join(rows)      
        column_index = single_row.find(word)        
        if column_index >= 0:
            return([column_index, row_index])

def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word):

    if find_word_horizontal or find_word_vertical is not True:
        result = []
        for w in crosswords:            
            for l in w:
                if l in word:
                    result.append(l.upper())                        
                else:
                    result.append(l)
        return result
        #return [[l.upper() if l in word else l for l in w] for w in crosswords]
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'

print(capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word))
```

This is the codes for finding specific word in a crosswords.

Here I developed two helper functions to find word horizontally and vertically. If both a horizontal and a vertical match is found then only horizontal match will return with capitalizes the matched characters in 2-dimensional list and returns the list. e.g., in my above code it should print:

```
[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','C','A','T'],['t','e','t','k']]
```

If no match is found, this function simply returns the original 2-dimensional list with no modification.

But my code returns `['s','d','o','g','C','u','C','m','A','C','A','T','T','e','T','k']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crossword,word):

    if not crossword or not word:
        return None

    word_find_horizontal_at= find_word_horizontal(crossword,word)
    if word_find_horizontal_at:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            crossword[word_find_horizontal_at[0]][word_find_horizontal_at[1]+i]=crossword[word_find_horizontal_at[0]][word_find_horizontal_at[1]+i].upper()
        return crossword

    word_find_vertical_at= find_word_vertical(crossword,word)
    if word_find_vertical_at:
        for j in range(len(word)):
            crossword[word_find_vertical_at[0]+j][word_find_vertical_at[1]]=crossword[word_find_vertical_at[0]+j][word_find_vertical_at[1]].upper()
    return crossword
```

This code gives the correct result.